# XML appendNode in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

My XML file like something like this:

```
<entity xsi:type="marketObservation">
  <date>2015-01-21</date>
  <marketInputDef xsi:type="transientRef" ref="EUR_FRA"/>
  <value>0.01958</value>
</entity>
```

I am trying to add some nodes to `<date>`  node by using append.xmlNode() function in R (example):

```
append.xmlNode(a[[1]][[1]], xmlNode('a', 56))
```

Assuming that my XML file is parsed into **a** variable

but I received a warning:

> Error in UseMethod("append") : 
>     no applicable method for 'append' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalElementNode', 'XMLInternalNode', 'XMLAbstractNode')"

Is there maybe any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too, I ended up using newXMLNode() and specified the 'parent'